# eksctl apply cluster changes after create

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I've created a cluster using

```
eksctl create cluster -f mycluster.yaml
```

everything is running but now I would want to add cluster autoscaler. There does not seem to be an option to specify this for the `eksctl update cluster` command.

When creating a new cluster I can add the --asg-access flag, is there an option to enable ASG support for an existing cluster via eksctl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--asg-access` flag only adds relevant iam policy and labels to a node group.
You can do that by creating a new node group with the autoscaler option set as true

```
nodeGroup:
  iam:
    withAddonPolicies:
      autoScaler: true
```

and the labels as mentioned [here](https://eksctl.io/usage/autoscaling/)

Then you need to install the autoscaler itself

Note:

You won't be able to edit your current nodeGroup, so you will have to add a new one first and then delete your current one. (https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/#nodegroup-immutability)